# Firebase DB fails to show queried list of objects

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason my `Adapter` isn't getting the updated list of objects, after some debugging i found out this: when i request the parsed List for my `Adapter` in `UpdateUI()`, the query wont start for some reason and gives back a empty list. Maybe I'm doing something in the wrong order? (just some random text cus i can't post the question)

```
public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ListFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Product> mProducts;

    public ProductListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static ProductListFragment newInstance() {
       return new ProductListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        updateUI();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        mProducts = DbOps.get(getActivity()).getProducts();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ListFragmentAdapter(mProducts);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


public class DbOps {
    private static DbOps sDbOps;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDb;
    private DatabaseReference dbRef;
    private List<Product> mProducts;
    private Product pr;

    public static DbOps get(Context ctx) {
        if (sDbOps == null) {
            sDbOps = new DbOps(ctx);
        }
        return sDbOps;
    }

    private DbOps(Context ctx) {
        mDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbRef = mDb.getReference().child("products");
        if(mProducts == null) {
            getProducts();
        }
    }

    public Product getProduct(final String mId) {
        Query query = dbRef.child(mId);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot obj: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if(obj.getValue(Product.class).getId().equals(mId)) {
                            pr = obj.getValue(Product.class);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return pr;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        dbRef.child(product.getId()).setValue(product);
    }


    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot mObject : dataSnapshot.getChildren());
                mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
                Product pr = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                mProducts.add(pr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(listener);
        return mProducts;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably a matter of asynchronous call. You should send an instance of an interface for DbOps and refresh your UI after getProducts return something. Check MVP patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return an object of `Product` class in the way you do, it will always be null due the asyncronious behaviour of `onDataChange()` method which is called before even you are trying to get the data from your database. So to solve this problem, you have 2 options:

1. You need to use and declare the `pr` object inside the `onDataChange()` method like this:

   ```
   query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               for (DataSnapshot obj: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   if(obj.getValue(Product.class).getId().equals(mId)) {
                       Product pr = obj.getValue(Product.class);
                       //do what you want to do with pr
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
   });
   ```
2. If you want to use the value of `pr` object outside `onDataChange() method`, then please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).